# How can I save ints to be retained even when the application is not running?

Tags: android, save

When I click on an option I want a check sign to appear to show it has been purchased. I am using `SharedPreferences` and have made all the links; however, when I click back or exit and then re-enter the application, the check is gone and any history of anything I did before is gone. How do I save the data so that it is kept even when the application is off or I'm at another page in the game. This is my code so far:

```
ImageView tick1;
int mYellCheck, mYellCheck1;
public static String sharedPrefs = "MyData";
SharedPreferences data;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
int mYellAlpha;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upgrades);
    update();
    coins = Replay.totalCoins + Replay4.totalCoins + Replay5.totalCoins
        + Replay6.totalCoins;
    data = getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefs, MODE_PRIVATE);
    tick1.setAlpha(mYellCheck);
}

public void update() {
    TextView coinScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
    coinScore.setText("You have " + coins + " coins");
    tick1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivtick1);
    ImageView moreYellow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivMoreYellow);
    ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.ivBack);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    moreYellow.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ivMoreYellow:
        mYellAlpha = 255;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
        editor.putInt("MoreYellowUpgrade", mYellAlpha);
        editor.commit();
        data = getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefs, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mYellCheck = data.getInt("MoreYellowUpgrade", 0);
        tick1.setAlpha(mYellCheck);
        break;
    case R.id.ivBack:
        Intent i = new Intent ("m.k.zaman.SpotActivity");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

or Should i just use internal storage?

Comment: Um. You set coins in the constructor, but not until after calling update(), and update() reads from coins. Also, where do the values in Replay, Replay4, Replay5 and Replay6 get set? Should they be being set from SharedPreferences? In onClick() you set `mYellCheck = data.getInt("MoreYellowUpgrade", 0)`, and in the constructor you load data then use mYellCheck but don't establish the relationship between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your current onClick call to R.id.ivMoreYellow with this:

```
case R.id.ivMoreYellow:
    mYellAlpha = 255;
    mYellCheck = data.getInt("MoreYellowUpgrade", 0);
    tick1.setAlpha(mYellCheck);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    editor.putInt("MoreYellowUpgrade", mYellAlpha);
    editor.commit();
    break;
```

You were first overwriting all of the data in the SharedPreferences, and then calling to receive that data that you just overwrote, so I placed the getInt() call before the putInt(). Do you change mYellAplha to anything other than 255 though? If you don't you will never notice a change in SharedPreferences if you are always saving and getting 255.

Comment: Thanks, the code woorks but when i got back to the homepage and then again to this (the upgrade) page, the check is missing and the saved data isnt there

Comment: I think you should really scrap everything down to the very basics so you can understand how SharedPreferences work. Start with just getting a boolean to save in a SharedPreferences file. Create a boolean "myBoolean" with an inital value of false, then in the onCreate() do a data.getBoolean("Boolean", false); with a System.out.println(myBoolean); to verify that it loads false first. Then click a button to change the boolean value to true and do editor.putBoolean("Boolean", myBoolean); editor.commit(); Next close your application fully, load it back up and your output should show true.

Comment: Thanks, i did what you said and used your code and I've fixed my problem. Thanks man